# pdo_mysql how to load extension in Apache

Tags: php

Please help me I have installed pdo_mysql through pecl install pdo_mysql. How to load this extension in PHP? somehow it won't read my PHP.ini having extension=pdo.so, extension=pdo_mysql.so?

If someone know how to resolve this issue? Please guide me.

By the way I install my PHP from source, using the latest PHP 5.4.30

Comment: Did you restart apache after updating the php.ini file?

Comment: Did you use the correct `php.ini` file?  In most server installations there are separate ini files for web server module running PHP and PHP CLI.

Answer (score 0):

On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```